# Win32_Process create on remote machine with the target on a share

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to execute a program from a ASP.NET website that is located on a share(that points to another machine) on a remote machine. Here is what the configuration looks like

Website server=>Computer A (with share that points to) =>Computer B (exe is here)

If I pass the following argument for the processName z:\tools\bin\myprogram.exe I get a return code of path not found. If I pass the following argument for the process name \\computerB\tools\bin\myprogram.exe I get an access denied error.

```
private static int CreateRemoteProcess(string serverName, string username, string password, string processName, params string[] arguments)
{
    var connection = new ConnectionOptions
    {
        Username = username,
        Password = password
    };

    var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + serverName + @"\root\cimv2", connection);
    using (var managementClass = new ManagementClass(scope,
                                                    new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"),
                                                    new ObjectGetOptions()))
    {
        var inputParams = managementClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
        if (arguments != null)
        {
            foreach (var param in arguments)
            {
                processName += " " + param;
            }
        }

        inputParams["CommandLine"] = processName;
        var outParams = managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create",
                                                     inputParams,
                                                     new InvokeMethodOptions());
        outParams = managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inputParams, null);
        var ret = Convert.ToInt32(outParams["ReturnValue"]);
        return Convert.ToInt32(outParams["ProcessId"]);
    }
```

Comment: is there a `z:` drive on that target machine..? also what account is setup for the user / password on the remote machine.. can you create a service account for what you are trying to do..?

Comment: Yes and it points to computerB.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass drive letters but use the full UNC path.

Z: drive is unknown and not mapped for the user you pass with the "username" variable. (you may think it is but it is not)